# Passing value, NULL or don't-update-this-column to an Oracle table update stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'd like to write an Oracle stored procedure to update a table on the database, where there's a way to give (or not give) a columname parameter to the procedure means "don't update this column". This is not quite the same thing as

```
update tablename set
       columnname = nvl(p_columnname, columnname),
       ...
where  key        = p_key
```

If you do that, you can't null out the column. I want to be able to null out the column too. If Oracle supported the typeless keyword UNKNOWN, I could say p_columname varchar2 := UNKNOWN, and test for omission of the parameter in a custom function. But without that, it gets hairy defining magic values that mean "don't update that column", one for each datatype, so that I don't error off on comparison of incompatible datatypes.

This seems like SUCH a common problem (one stored procedure to handle all updates to a table, without requiring a read-before-write select for columns you aren't changing). Surely someone's figured out a best practice to handle it. Hope so anyway. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally i would use a different stored procedure *per transaction*, with the exact SQL needed for that use case (of course, using helper stored procedures if needed). I have found  that "table" stored procedures are not very useful (I must confess that I have been exposed to high doses of http://asktom.oracle.com/)

Comment: I agree. I use table stored procedures only when I have to, either (a) because the update is tricky or (b) my client has a standard dictating their use. Either way, the reason for implementing table stored procedures is to move processing logic to the database, and if the caller has to set a bunch of columns to null or other specious values, that's a sign the processing logic has bled away from the database. I'd recommend a different procedure per transaction as well, and put them into a package. You can give them the same name if you want - Oracle supports overloading.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. Unfortunately, I don't decide which columns get updated. The customer does, and sends me minimal XML containing only the columns that changed. Creating a stored procedure for every possible combination of columns would be a combinatorial explosion.

Answer (score 1):

There's a balance to be struck here between providing the perfectly focussed update on one hand, and ease of development by updating everything on the other. They can both have negative performance implications.

When you update every column there's obviously an overhead in increased redo, increased undo, higher load on the redo logs, longer wait for log file syncs, possibility of superfluous foreign key value checks, etc.. Poor performance often equals time lost by developers in troubleshooting and redeveloping.

However on the other hand if every update is perfectly focussed then instead of one update statement in the shared pool you might now have five, ten , twenty, etc -- however many combinations of changes are possible. That's a bad thing in itself and can lead to an increase in hard parsing, and to time lost later in troubleshooting.

The middle ground is probably to try to identify the more common types of update (eg. change phone number, update order status, etc) and provide dedicated updates for those, and to send the rest (hopefully a small minority) to a general update.

To be extra careful you might consider logging every 60th use of the general update to see exactly what is changing, and try to pick up on any unexpectedly common combinations (or developers using the wrong update API) by checking:

```
extract(second from systimestamp) < 1
```

... or something.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. Unfortunately, there hasn't been any pattern to the columns to be updated. I keep an audit trail of the incoming XML and could build correlation matrix of XML tags (which map to database columns). Sure would be nicer to detect a "don't update this column" condition in the procedure, however.

Comment: How many unique update combinations are you dealing with, do you think?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conditionally set a column, you can do so using a case statement:

```
update table
set    column = case 
                  when <your condition here> then 
                    column
                  else 
                    parameter
                end
```

This sets the column to itself (i.e. no update) when your "no update condition" is met. You'll need to decide what parameters you'll need to identify this. The advantage this provides over nvl is allows you to set the column to null if you need to.